# Update dropdown options in live Google Form using Apps Script

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown, google-forms

i'm fairly new to google app script and i have a problem with my code.

I use the following code to update company entities to a google form drop down. The dropdown is used in multiple sections in the form (as you can fill it in for multiple entities).

Updating works fine but it only updates the first section that uses the dropdown resulting in having to remove the others en duplicating the updated dropdown.

Is it possible to automatically update all sections ??

Please help!

```
var ssID = "[SheetID]";
var formID = "[SheetID]";
var ssPlanningID = "[SheetID]";

var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssPlanningID).getSheetByName("[SheetNAME]");
var form = FormApp.openById(formID);


function Dropdown() {
  var title = "Entity name";
  var values = wsData.getRange(4, 1, wsData.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().map(function(o){ return o[0] }).filter(function(o){return o !== "" });

  var items = form.getItems();
  var titles = items.map(function(item){
    return item.getTitle();
  });

  var values = values.sort();
  var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
  var item = items[pos];
  var itemID = item.getId();

  updateDropdown(itemID,values);
}


function updateDropdown(id,values) {

  var item = form.getItemById(id);
  item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
}

//DROPDOWN VAN ENTITY NAME UPDATE


function DropdownEntityName() {
  var title = "Entity name";
  var values = wsData.getRange(3, 1, wsData.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().map(function(o){ return o[0] }).filter(function(o){return o !== "" }); 

  Logger.log(values);
  var newdata = new Array();
  for(nn in values){
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newdata){
      if(values[nn] == newdata[j]){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newdata.push([values[nn]]);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(newdata);
  var newdata = newdata.sort();
//  newdata.sort(function(x,y){
//  var xp = Number(x[0]);// ensure you get numbers
//  var yp = Number(y[0]);
//  return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;// sort on numeric ascending
//});
  Logger.log(newdata);
 //sh.getRange(1,5,newdata.length,newdata[0].length).setValues(newdata);// paste new values sorted in column of your choice (here column 5, indexed from 1, we are on a sheet))


  var items = form.getItems();
  var titles = items.map(function(item){
    return item.getTitle();
  });

  var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
  var item = items[pos];
  var itemID = item.getId();

  updateDropdownEN(itemID,newdata);
}


function updateDropdownEN(id,values) {

  var item = form.getItemById(id);
  item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
}
```

Comment: This probably isn't the problem but this `wsData.getRange(4, 1, wsData.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().map(function(o){ return o[0] }).filter(function(o){return o !== "" });` should be this `wsData.getRange(4, 1, wsData.getLastRow()-3,1).getValues().map(function(o){ return o[0] }).filter(function(o){return o !== "" });`

Comment: My understanding is that you can't interact with the form once it is presented to the end user.   So it is not possible to utilize dependent dropdowns since you can't get the answer to the first drop down to be used in the second until the form is submitted and the of course then it is too late.

Comment: You can do this easily in a web app using google.script.run.  Take a look at the guides section of the documentation Guides/Types of Scripts/webapps